# C# MVC application unwanted redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been playing around with the ASP.net C# MVC Framework attempting to program some kind of Assessment Test. I'm fairly new to ASP.net (quite fluent in C#) however, I'm constantly getting the same weird result:

Ok. How it works is basically that a question with some answers appear -> the user has to select the answer he/she thinks  is correct and click proceed (Button 'Next'). Well, what I do is I'm reading all the questions/answers and other information from an xml file (works correctly no doubt about that I can see it in the debugger the correct information). However what I know want to do is after completing about 18 questions to redirect the user to some sort of results page

```
public ActionResult Result()
        {

            ViewBag.Message = "Your result page.";

            return View(_questionProcessing);
        }
```

which is ment to be invoked when all questions are answered (call from Question method). 
However it already jumps to the results page after the 4th question for some reason.

I've been debugging the application for several hours now but haven't been able to find the cause.

If someone could please help, Thank you very much!

The Question cshtml

```
@using Assessify.Models
@model Assessify.Models.QuestionProcessing
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Question";
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Question.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
}


<div class="container outerQuestionContainer">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 well">
            <h2>Question @((Model.questionIterator + 1).ToString())</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="imageToQuestion">

                        <img src="@Model.QuestionModels.Questions[Model.questionIterator].Bildurl" class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="myImagetitle" id="questionImage"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="well cFragesatz">
                        @Html.Label("Expression", Model.QuestionModels.Questions[Model.questionIterator].Fragesatz)
                    </div>


                    <div class="divAntworten">
                        <div class="divAntwort" style="color: white">

                            @foreach (Antwort antwort in Model.QuestionModels.Questions[Model.questionIterator].Antworten)
                            {
                                <div class="well divAntwortStyle">

                                    @Html.CheckBox(antwort.Antwortphrase, false)
                                    @Html.Label(antwort.Antwortphrase)

                                </div>       
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row rowButton">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        @{
                            Model.questionIterator = Model.questionIterator + 1;
                        }
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="width: 100%"> @Html.ActionLink("Next", "Question", "Home", new {counter = Model.questionIterator}, null)</button>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

The Data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Assessify.Models
{
    public class QuestionModels
    {
        public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

        public QuestionModels(String Path)
        {
            var xdox = XElement.Load(Path);

            var e = from c in xdox.Descendants("Frage")
                    select new Question()
                    {
                        FrageId = int.Parse((string) c.Attribute("fNumb").Value),
                        Category = (string)c.Attribute("fCategory").Value,
                        Fragesatz = (string)c.Element("Fragesatz").Value,
                        Bildurl = (string)c.Element("Bildurl").Value,
                        Antworten = from a in c.Elements("Antwort")
                                    select new Antwort()
                                    {
                                        Antwortphrase = a.Value,
                                        isTheCorrect = Boolean.Parse((string) a.Attribute("isTrue").Value)
                                    }
                    };
            Questions = e.ToList();

        }

    }

    public class Question
    {
        public String Fragesatz { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Antwort> Antworten { get; set; }
        public int FrageId { get; set; }
        public String Bildurl { get; set; }
        public String Category { get; set; }

        public Boolean wasAnsweredCorrectly = false;

        public Decimal Weight { get; set; } 

    }

    public class Antwort
    {
        public String Antwortphrase { get; set; }
        public Boolean isTheCorrect { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace Assessify.Models
{
    public class QuestionProcessing
    {
    public QuestionModels QuestionModels { get; set; }
    public int questionIterator { get; set; }

    public QuestionProcessing(String link)
    {
        QuestionModels = new QuestionModels(link);
        questionIterator = 0;
    }

}
```

The Homecontroller:

```
namespace Assessify.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        QuestionProcessing _questionProcessing = new QuestionProcessing(@"C:\Users\thoma\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Assessify\Assessify\Models\Ressources\Fragefile_new.xml");

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(); 
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Question(int counter = 0)     
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your question page.";

            this._questionProcessing.questionIterator = counter;

            if (_questionProcessing.questionIterator >= _questionProcessing.QuestionModels.Questions.Count)
            {

                return RedirectToActionPermanent("Result");
            }

            return View(this._questionProcessing);
        }

        public ActionResult Result()
        {

            ViewBag.Message = "Your result page.";

            return View(_questionProcessing);
        }



    }
}
```

RouteConfig:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Assessify
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Question",
                url: "Home/Question/{counter}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Question", counter = UrlParameter.Optional }

            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, controllers are instantiated and destroyed with each request. As a result, you should keep in mind that your `QuestionProcessing` instance will be new for each request, too. You may already be aware of that, but I get nervous whenever I see people manually setting ivars on controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *probably* don't want this:

```
RedirectToActionPermanent("Result");
```

This responds to the browser with the HTTP response code [301 Moved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) indicating that resource it just asked for will *always* result in a redirect, and it should just request the redirected resource instead on its own.

But that's not what you want. You want the browser to continue to request the `Question` resource until you *explicitly* tell it to perform a redirect, which is what this will do:

```
RedirectToAction("Result");
```

This responds with the HTTP response code [302 Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302), which tells the browser to redirect the user "this time", but not necessarily in future requests.

Basically, if during your testing you ever made a request that resulted in that redirect, all future requests from that browser could go directly to the redirected page without submitting the request to the server.

**Note:** You may need to clear client-side data from your browser to remove that effect at this time, since you've already told the browser to permanently redirect.